# Qt on Mac saying symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, qt, signals-slots, macos-sierra

Hi I'm using Qt to create a Minesweeper game in macOS, and whenever I wrote some signals and slots to my classes my app won't compile. Qt says `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`
So here's my code:

```
enum Status {
    virgin,
    flagged,
    questioned,
    revealed
};
class Cell : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    int atRow;
    int atCol;
    int content;//0 - 8 means the numbers of mines around the cell. -1 means it's a mine itself.
    bool isMine;
    Status status;
    Cell(int atRow, int atCol);

    Cell *NorthWest,
    *North,
    *NorthEast,
    *East,
    *SouthEast,
    *South,
    *SouthWest,
    *West;


public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

};
```

I've seen many questions similar to mine but I was not able to solve this. I tried adding `CONFIG -= x86_64` but it's still not working. And I know it's the `MOC` thing but I don't know how to solve it.
Someone help me please!

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have finally found the solution on this page:
[Qt Creator: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119189/qt-creator-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)
I tried and it worked. But I'm not sure it's completely correct so anyone holding different opinions Please post an answer here.